# Unknown Electrical Component

Tags: components

I was doing some work on a blown circuit board and I cam across two identical components I had never seen before. One looks burnt so I think that might be the problem. The whole board is designed to operate at up to 1200 watts so I think it might just be a large ceramic resistor. I'm not sure though. Attached are pictures of the blown one and the normal one. 
Thanks
[image: good part]

[image: bad part]

Comment: Your picture-posting fu isn't too good. No images. You might run a spell check on the title while you're at it.

Comment: @Transistor my computer decided to post this draft. I fixed it though

Comment: A pessimistic outlook (hey, its Monday): an overheated, stressed component like this power resistor is often a result of a fault somewhere else. A catastrophic fault is often easier to fix than a fault that causes slow death.

Comment: @glen_geek so I should just check all the conections

Comment: The 2nd photo shows the resistor without a spring clip. Have you lost it? It is quite important to hold the resistor against the heatsink.

Comment: those ceramic reisstors can run verrrrry hot, so 'looks burnt' may not be diagnostic.

Comment: Doesn't look blown just hot. I'd check whatever semiconductors it is connected to and see if one of them died.

Comment: There are quite a few parts on both pictures.  It is unclear which part you are referring to.

Comment: @SteveG I was disassembleling it when I took this picture. It was there and I do have it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They look like your classic ceramic-packaged wire-wound power resisters.  Not my first suspect when something fails because they are only slightly more complicated than a rock, very hard to kill.

Comment: It looks burned to me. I'm not sure though

Comment: Easy enough to measure, but I concur, it got hot, but they do that. And those things are normally very, very reliable. I would be looking elsewhere, starting with the power sand.